# Apps daemonized with pm2 not working with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, http-status-code-404, pm2

Firstly, I'm sorry about my poor english and also I warn you that i'm a newbie still learning those technologies that I'm going to talk about.

So, I work on a companie and they needed some simple pages apps. I choose to use the React.js technologie with an Node.js API running with Express. (Sorry if I am wrong about the terms but I'm not english and still student).

I've done my 2 react apps and my api that are actually working correctly. I must deploy them on a CentOs. SO I've "daemonized" my 2 react apps and my API. The first react app with the port :8080, the other one with the port :3000 and the api, with the port :8081.

Then I installed Nginx, with a simple conf. It worked well. After that I've been trying to use https. So I did. But I'm now facing a problem.

When I try to reach one of my apps, I got a blank page with those messages :

```
GET https://domain_name/src/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404    (index):19 
GET https://domain_name/static/js/2.3d1c602b.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404  (index):20 
GET https://domain_name/static/js/main.95db8d0e.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404   manifest.json:1 
GET https://domain_name/manifest.json 404  manifest.json:1 
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

And if I try to reach one of my api routes I get this :

```
Cannot GET /api/oneThing
```

and :

```
GET https://patt_www_ppd/api/ 404     patt_www_ppd/:1
```

I couldn't figure out with the problem in the net. I've found some possible solutions but I didn't understood them or it didn't worked. Can somebody help me?

Here is my nginx.conf :

```
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    log_not_found off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 16M;

    # MIME
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # SSL
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    # Mozilla Intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    # load configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And here is my domain_name.conf under the /sites-available/ directory :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name domain_name;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/certifs/domain_name.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certifs/domain_name.key;

    # security
    include nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_name.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_name.error.log warn;

    # reverse proxy
    location /inventaire/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }

    location /ticket/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        include nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf;
    }



    # additional config
    include nginxconfig.io/general.conf;
}

# subdomains redirect
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name *.domain_name;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/certifs/domain_name.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certifs/domain_name.key;

    return 301 https://domain_name$request_uri;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .domain_name;

    return 301 https://domain_name$request_uri;
}
```

I really thank anyone that can bring me some answers... And again, sorry for my english and my poor abilities in this domain, but I'm still learning.

Comment: Have you checked the status of your pm2 using pm2 list? Make sure the process has been activated as a service so that it doesn't stop on reboot.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Thank you for your answer. I've checked it and the services are all online. It can't be this.